# Value Dispose() cannot be called while doing CreateHandle() Error when Using Thread

Tags: c#

//This is my code

```
private void btnGenSumm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(loadSummSales));
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(showWaitMessage));
    t1.Start();
    t2.Start();  
    }      

private void showWaitMessage()  
{            
    label1.Text = "Processing please wait!";  
}      

private void loadSummSales()    
{  
    try  
    {  
        sqlConn = new SqlConnection(MyClass.GlobalConn());    

        string cmdStr = "[dbo].[GetSummary]";    

        sqlConn.Open();    

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, sqlConn);    

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;    
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@piDateFrom", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(FromD);    
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@piDateThru", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(ToD);  

        System.Data.DataTable dT = new System.Data.DataTable();    
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);    
        da.Fill(dT);    
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
        dgSummSales.DataSource = dT;    

        dgSummSales.Columns["Branch"].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;    
        dgSummSales.Columns["Product Amt"].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;    
        dgSummSales.Columns["SERVICE Amt"].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;    

        dgSummSales.Columns["Branch"].Width = 270;  
        dgSummSales.Columns["Product Amt"].Width = 98;  
        dgSummSales.Columns["SERVICE Amt"].Width = 103;  

        dgSummSales.Columns["Product Amt"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";  
        dgSummSales.Columns["SERVICE Amt"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";  

        dgSummSales.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;  
        dgSummSales.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Aquamarine;  

        dgSummSales.Refresh();

        label1.Text = "Sales as of " + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("d", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
    }
```

//On my first click  btnGenSumm button, it has no error, but on my second try, it gives an error

Value `Dispose()` cannot be called while doing `CreateHandle()`. on `Designer.cs`
but when I don't used Thread it has no error when I click  `btnGenSumm` button many times.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the specific problems you're experiencing at the moment, this code is fundamentally broken.

You cannot manipulate UI elements on any thread but the main UI thread. Both of your background threads execute code that interacts directly with UI elements (e.g., controls on your form) as if it were running on the main UI thread. That is not going to work.

Change your code to use the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) component instead. This handles cross-thread access of UI elements much more elegantly than the alternatives. The linked MSDN documentation contains sample code, and you can find plenty of other questions here on Stack Overflow about it by using the handy-dandy search feature.

Comment: I already try backgroundworker for this, but i got the same error!